Can the natural density of prime numbers be used to prove Bronte's postulate?
At present, the  Bertrand's postulate by can be proved by Tchebychev’s method and Erdös’s method.
I am here mainly to explore a new way of thinking, to see whether the natural density of primes can be used to prove Bronte's postulate.
It is well known that even numbers(2P) set for 1/2 of the total natural numbers, while triple numbers(3P)  set  for 1/3. We see that the 3P set  is less than the 2P set .
Thus there is the following prime density sequence:
$$
\frac{1}{2} >\frac{1}{3}> \frac{1}{5}... \frac{1}{p_{n}}>\frac{1}{p_{n+1}}
$$
With inequality，
$$
\frac{1}{p_{n}}+\frac{1}{p_{n+1}}<\frac{1}{p_{n}}+\frac{1}{p_{n}}
$$
We know that the 2P set already contains some elements of the 3P set, so:
$$
\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3} < \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}
$$
That is, the interval (2, 4] contains the prime number 3.
If there are no new primes in the interval (2, 4], it means that the interval (2, 4] has only elements of the 2P set, that is, there are no new prime factors equal to 3 and related multiples of 3. It means:
$$
\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}
$$
Contradictory.
Similarly, if there are no new primes in the interval ($p_{n}, 2p_{n}$]  , it means that only prime factors in the interval ($p_{n}, 2p_{n}$] are equal to the primes in the interval (2, $2p_{n}$], that is, no new prime factors are equal to $p_{n+1}$ and related multiples of $p_{n+1}$. It means:
$$
\frac{1}{p_{n}}+\frac{1}{p_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{p_{n}}+\frac{1}{p_{n}}
$$
Contradictory.
This is just my immature idea, do not know this method of proof is right?

Welcome to MSE. Before asking any questions please search it in Approach zero website. https://approach0.xyz/search/

What is Bronte's postulate?  Just to say:  it's hard to use density arguments to prove that something has to hold in every finite interval...density arguments might be able to prove that they hold infinitely often or something like that.

@lulu Yes, I also agree with you that densities are more like wholes and prime's intervals are partial. We can say that there are infinitely many prime triples or 3-term arithmetic progressions, but we can't use that to prove that there are infinitely many twin prime.
